# Несоответствие результатов нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Есть нейронная сеть определяющая тональность отзывов о фильмах(хороший/плохой). Использовал датасет `imdb` Для взвешивания терминов использовал TF-IDF. Тип сети - многослойный персептрон. Суть проблемы - на выходе сеть выдает точность 87% на тестовых данных. После работы сети я подал ту же тестовую выборку на уже обученную сеть для проверки результата и получил в итоге 9237 несоответствий, что почти 40%, но никак не 13. Откуда такое расхождение?
Модель сети:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras import optimizers

def flatten(iterable, types_to_flatten=(list, tuple)):
    for it in iterable:
        if isinstance(it, types_to_flatten):
            yield from flatten(it)
        else:
            yield it

def get_data(path):
    p = Path(path)
    train = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                       for f in p.glob('train_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    test = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                      for f in p.glob('test_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    return ((train['Text'], train['Sentiment']),
           (test['Text'], test['Sentiment']))

# read data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = get_data(r'D:\download\NLP')

# build vocabulary
t = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
t.fit_on_texts(X_train)
t.fit_on_texts(X_test)


# build a model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=10000))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimiz = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = optimiz ,metrics = ['accuracy'])

# convert texts to TF-IDF matrices
X_train = t.texts_to_matrix(X_train, mode='tfidf')
X_test = t.texts_to_matrix(X_test, mode='tfidf')

# fit the model
hist = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 5,batch_size = 64)
```

Так проверяю результат:

```
X1=X_test.values.tolist()
X2=y_test.values.tolist()

X3 = np.asarray(X2)
t.fit_on_texts(X1)
X = t.texts_to_matrix(X1, mode='tfidf')

X3=X3.tolist()
X3=np.asarray(X3)

X4=list(flatten(np.round(model.predict(X)).tolist()))
X4=np.asarray(X4)

(X4 != X3).sum()
```

В результате 9237 несоответствий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После данных строк:

```
# convert texts to TF-IDF matrices
X_train = t.texts_to_matrix(X_train, mode='tfidf')
X_test = t.texts_to_matrix(X_test, mode='tfidf')
```

`X_train`, `X_test` - уже векторизированы и готовы к тому чтобы подавать их напрямую модели.

Что (главное зачем?) делает следующий код я не понимаю:

```
X1=X_test.values.tolist()
X2=y_test.values.tolist()

X3 = np.asarray(X2)
t.fit_on_texts(X1)
X = t.texts_to_matrix(X1, mode='tfidf')
```

---

Если скормить модели `X_test` без повторных преобразований, то точность модели будет ожидаемая:

```
# predict values
In [17]: pred = np.round(model.predict(X_test))

# flatten `pred` to 1D vector
In [18]: pred = pred.ravel()

# number of mistakes (wrong predictions)    
In [19]: (pred != y_test).sum()
Out[19]: 3106

# model's accuracy 
In [20]: (pred == y_test).mean()
Out[20]: 0.87576
```

Comment: Да, что-то я перемудрил, спасибо.